# Return user to last step on next visit reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am creating a long on-boarding process. It is possible that a user might not complete the process during one visit. I would like to return a user to the step he/she left from on the next visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it depends on situation.

`Authenticated user`

Here I would suggest to store steps state on back-end side. You will have possibility to restore it even in situation when user authenticated on another device/browser.

`Guest`

Here I would suggest to store steps state in local storage, and restore it whenever you need.